# Python script to edit addon settings

Tags: python, scripting, command-line, network

I am trying to use python to script to change the settings of the Network Render addon. I am attempting to change the tags in the slave that way I don't have to change my blend every time. I am using a python script to enable CUDA but I can't figure out how to properly reference the settings for addons. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my slave.bat

```
blender -P script.py -b slave.blend --addons netrender -a -noaudio -nojoystick
```

Here is the script.py

```
import bpy
bpy.context.user_preferences.system.compute_device_type = 'CUDA'
```

Comment: After digging deeper into the Api I found the render settings were in the 'type'. I edited the plugin to include a button that adds the tag in the settings panel and then enable the button with

    bpy.types.NetRenderSettings.slave_pm = True

Hopefully that will help someone.

Comment: While this happens to work, its incorrect - You're editing the type so all instances will be `True`, but what you attempted the first time was the correct method.

Comment: What exactly did you edit? And what exactly did you mean the first time? The first time I wasn't even talking about the Netrender settings, just the cuda.

What would be the correct way to assign the bool then?